# edit two separate draggable in the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to edit text separately how can I do this? I want to click on one at a time and edit the one I click on please help I would like to make this as easy as possible later on I would like to edit more things but for now this will ok

```js
var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'ui-widget-content',
        appendTo: '.container',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    });
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function()
{
    $(this).hide();    $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function()
{
    return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function()
{
    var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
    if (editingText.length)
    {
        editingText.hide();
        editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
    }
});

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).draggable();
    }
};

var vm=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.items=ko.observableArray();
    self.textContent = ko.observable('');
    self.init=function(){
        self.items([]);
    }
    self.remove=function(item){
        console.log(item);
        self.items.remove(item);
    }
    self.addNew = function() {
      self.items.push( self.textContent() );
      self.textContent('');
    }
    self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());

$("#fs").change(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    $('.item').css("font-family", $(this).val());

});
```

```css
<style>.item{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background:transparent;
    z-index: 1;
    display:block;
}

.edit_text
{
    display: none;
}

.fix_backround
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid;
}
</style><style>
.thumbs img{
  margin:3px;
  width:50px;
  float:left;
}</style>
<style>
.bottlesWrapper img{
  margin:3px;
  width:400px;
  float:left;
}</style>
<style>#main { border:1px solid #eee; margin:20px; width:410px; height:220px;}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .transparent { background:transparent }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">​
```

```html
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
 
   

    <select id="fs"> 
        <option value="Agency FB">Agency FB</option>
        <option value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
        <option value="AR Berkley">AR Berkley</option>
        <option value="AR Blanca">AR Blanca</option>
        <option value="AR Bonnie">AR Bonnie</option>
        <option value="AR Carter">AR Carter</option>
        <option value="AR Cena">AR Cena</option>
        <option value="AR Christy">AR Christy</option>
        <option value="AR Darling">AR Darling</option>
        <option value="AR Decode">AR Decode</option>
        <option value="AR Delaney">AR Delaney</option>
        <option value="AR Destine">AR Destine</option>
        <option value="AR Essence">AR Essence</option>
        <option value="AR HERMANN">AR Hermann</option>
        <option value="AR JULIAN">AR Julian</option>
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
        <option value="Arial Narrow">Arial Narrow</option>
        <option value="Arial Rounded MT Bold">Arial Rounded MT Bold</option>
        <option value="Baskerville Old Face">Baskerville Old Face</option>
        <option value="Bell MT">Bell MT</option>
        <option value="Berlin Sans FB">Berlin Sans FB</option>
        <option value="Berlin Sans FB Demi">Berlin Sans FB Demi</option>
        <option value="Bernard MT Condensed">Bernard MT Condensed</option>
        <option value="Blackadder ITC">Blackadder ITC</option>
        <option value="Bodoni MT">Bodoni MT</option>
        <option value="Bodoni MT Black">Bodoni MT Black</option>
        <option value="Bodoni MT Condensed">Bodoni MT Condensed</option>
        <option value="Bodoni MT Poster Compressed">Bodoni MT Poster Compressed</option>
        <option value="Book Antiqua">Book Antiqua</option>
        <option value="Bookman Old Style">Bookman Old Style</option>
        <option value="Bradley Hand ITC">Bradley Hand ITC</option>   
        <option value="Britannic Bold">Britannic Bold</option>
        <option value="Broadway">Broadway</option>
        <option value="Brush Script MT">Brush Script MT</option>
        <option value="Bodoni MT">Bodoni MT</option>
        <option value="Californian FB">Californian FB</option>
        <option value="Castellar">Castellar</option>
        <option value="Century Gothic">Century Gothic</option>
        <option value="Century Schoolbook">Century Schoolbook</option> 
        <option value="Chiller">Chiller</option>
        <option value="Colonna MT">Colonna MT</option> 
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
        <option value="Constantia">Constantia</option>
        <option value="Cooper Black">Cooper Black</option>
        <option value="Copperplate Gothic Bold">Copperplate Gothic Bold</option>
        <option value="Copperplate Gothic Light">Copperplate Gothic Light</option>
        <option value="Curlz MT">Curlz MT</option>
        <option value="Edwardian Script ITC">Edwardian Script ITC</option> 
       <option value="Elephant">Elephant</option>
       <option value="Engravers MT">Engravers MT</option>
       <option value="Eras Bold ITC">Eras Bold ITC</option>
       <option value="Eras Demi ITC">Eras Demi ITC</option>
       <option value="Eras Light ITC">Eras Light ITC</option>
       <option value="Eras Medium ITC">Eras Medium ITC</option>
       <option value="Felix Titling">Felix Titling</option>
       <option value="Footling MT Light">Footling MT Light</option>
       <option value="Forte">Forte</option>
    </select>
    
    <select id="size">
        <option value="8">8</option>
    


 
 </form>
<textarea data-bind="value: textContent" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
<button data-bind="click: addNew">Generate New Div</button>

<div class="container">
<div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
    <div href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
        <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span><br/><br/>
        <center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/></center>
    </div>
</div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it's working.. *hint hint* : (`double click`)

Comment: with this code you can add multiple text with different divs please try to add multiple text and when I try to edit they all turn the same text and what I want is to change individual  try adding another text after you enter the first one